# Is there a software/application that shows the FM base stations nearby us?

Tags: signal-detection, frequency-modulation, lte

I want to collect a list of FM base stations near me. I have found apps/software for finding LTE base station but found no success in finding an app for FM base station.

Comment: "FM" as in...broadcasting radio stations?

Comment: You could make your own based on GnuRadio.

Comment: Yeah. FM broadcasting radio stations.  For example, In cellmapper application, we can see the location of LTE base stations all around the city.  Is there a way in which I can check the FM base stations around the entire city?

Comment: In the US, the FCC maintains a data b as she of licensed transmitter locations

Comment: Yep, that would definitely make a nice GNURadio project. [That FCC list sure looks impressive too](https://transition.fcc.gov/fcc-bin/fmq?list=A).